# Eclipse Android Unicode Folder Names causing bad build

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my Android project, I put several folders with unicode names in the assets folder. Eg "Ελληνικά" and "中文（繁體）"

When I do so, I can not built the app. I get this error. However, when I rename the folders to simple ASCII it works.

```
[2010-07-21 21:12:58 - Ridvan Library] ------------------------------
[2010-07-21 21:12:58 - Ridvan Library] Android Launch!
[2010-07-21 21:12:58 - Ridvan Library] adb is running normally.
[2010-07-21 21:12:58 - Ridvan Library] Could not find Ridvan Library.apk!
```

Comment: `Patient:` "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." `Doctor:` "Don't do that". Is it that hard to avoid unicode when naming folders?

Comment: Very much so. Not all developers in the world speak English.

Comment: Why not?  All pilots do.

Comment: You manage to use English when overriding Java methods, using Java keywords, when creating Android `values` folders etc., so it should be manageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears Android does not yet fully support all Unicode in code and folders.